# Is there any way to undo for 2 remove items from cart with a single click into Woocommerce/wordpress?

Tags: woocommerce

So I hook "woocommerce_remove_cart_item" then from here, I remove a second item from cart and add a "notice" to restore it, so I got two notices to restore items, but:

Will be possible only one notice(showing both items) and restore both items with only one click ?

```
// Delete second item if CONDITION    
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        if ( CONDITION ) { 
            array_push($array_to_delete,$cart_item);
            }
        }

    //Unset all cart items selected
foreach( $array_to_delete as $cart_item ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    $prod_unique_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product->id );
    // Remove it from the cart by un-setting it
    unset( WC()->cart->cart_contents[$prod_unique_id] );

    //Add undo notice   
    $product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id'] );
    $item_removed_title = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed_title', $product ? sprintf( _x( '“%s”', 'Item name in quotes', 'woocommerce' ), $product->get_name() ) : __( 'Item', 'woocommerce' ), $cart_item ); 
    $removed_notice = sprintf( __( '%s removed.', 'woocommerce' ), $item_removed_title ); 
    $removed_notice .= ' <a href="' . esc_url( WC()->cart->get_undo_url( $cart_item_key ) ) . '">' . __( 'Undo?', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>'; 
    wc_add_notice( $removed_notice );
    */                  
    }
```

Comment: what version is your woocommerce? `get_undo_url` is deprecated in the current version.

Comment: today latest,  wordpress 4.9.6 and woocommerce 3.3.5